# Taylor vs Goldstein

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I'm trying to select a mechanics book for self-study. I have some math background (linear algebra and calculus among other things) and I want to pick a book that won't skip over the math. I would prefer something more rigorous and thorough. I see the names Taylor and Goldstein come up quite frequently and so I would like some help in understanding the differences between their books.